# Continuity of real polynomial roots within a component (non-zero dimension variety)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

I have an applied problem that deals with real multivariate polynomials systems (real coefficients with real roots).

If I understand this problem correctly, the (real) root numbers will remain unchanged within each topologically connected component (please correct me if I'm using a weird terminology here).

$\color{red}{\star}$ Is the real solutions to a polynomial system continuous with respect to the coefficients (in a [correspondence continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity#:%7E:text=A%20correspondence%20that%20has%20both%20properties%20is%20said,the%20property%20of%20the%20same%20name%20for%20functions.) sense if variety not **zero-dimensional**, meaning not finite here), at least within each connected component?

In the finite solutions case, if the solutions are continuous(complex or not), and root numbers are fixed within the component. Then if I just focus on the real ones, it seems like we automatically have continuity for the real solutions. However, this system's solutions are not required to be **zero-dimensional**. So far, all the books I found only talks about the zero-dimensional case. Would the continuity still hold?
Any comments or references are welcomed!

Comment: Good question! I think this should be true in a suitable sense if one excludes a "discriminant locus" (for the zero-dimensional case this is the locus where the roots have multiplicity) but I don't know what the precise statements are or where to find them.

Comment: Note that even if continuity holds, the roots may vary tremendously with only a small change in coefficients. Which may be a problem if you want to use this continuity in a numerical way. This is already the case with polynomials in one variable, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the comment! Glad to know my algorithm might still have some theoretical base!

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Thank you for the reference! Yes, I am aware of that consequence and have extended my precision level to 500 digits...